# Visual studio 2019 is getting 'access denied' on restoring packages on mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Im trying to restore solution packages in visual studio 2019 on my mac and i get 'access denied' on some folders. This error doesn't seem to have any pattern as some packages are actually restored in the same folder!

I have tried to run the app as sudo through the terminal and i still get the same error

```
Installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 3.1.6.
Acquiring lock for the installation of System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.7.0
Acquired lock for the installation of System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.7.0
Installing System.Text.Encodings.Web 4.7.0.
Access to the path '/Users/georgemukwewa/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe/4.3.0' is denied.
```

Can someone help me with this please!!

Comment: Delete the folder and try again? There is likely a permissioning problem on that folder - possibly you ran VS Mac or NuGet as superuser? Deleting the system.runtime.compilerservices folder may resolve the problem since that is a cache folder and the file will be downloaded again if it is missing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt Ward - that solved it for me